# Django + Javascript | Problemas al pasar valores django a array javascript

Tags: javascript, django

El programa compara la respuesta del usuario, con las respuestas posibles (que son varias las posibles correctas).
Para ello trato de insertar en un array las respuestas posibles (del ORM de Django a un array javascript), para después mediante un if comparar la respuesta del usuario con la respuesta posible (una a una).
Pero tengo algún error que hace que el array no funcione dentro del ese for de Django. ¿Qué sucede?

HTML:

```
<input id="respuestaUsuario" type="text">
<button onclick="corregir()">Corregir</button>
```

Javascript + Django:

```
<script>
    function corregir(){
        var resp = document.getElementById("respuestaUsuario").value;
        var cont=0;
        var array=new Array();

        {% for textoEUS in pregunta.textoEUS.all %}
            array[cont]="{{ textoEUS }}";
            if (resp == array[cont]){
                alert("Muy bien!");
            }
            cont=cont+1;
        {% endfor %}
</script>
```

Comment: En realidad por cada iteracion del bucle `for` se esta repitiendo el código dentro de dicho bucle, si quieres inspecciona el elemento desde el navegador para que lo veas. Por otra parte lograr tu objetivo es algo complicado en la forma en la cual lo quieres hacer ya que hay que encontrar la manera de que la iteracion sea de un bucle `for` de JavaScript, y la única solución (de la forma que quieres) seria que pases al contexto una lista con los textos **no los objetos**, y hacerlo de esta manera: `let x = {{ list }}`, así un bucle `for` de JavaScript podrá iterarlo y podrás lograr el objetivo.

Comment: Pero lo que te recomiendo es que hagas peticiones AJAX al backend y solicites los datos que necesites para hacer las respectivas validaciones.